# elasticsearch - search in multiple indixes failes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following indexes

```
➜ curl -s -X GET http://10.1.1.1:9200/_cat/indices\?v | grep "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12"
green  open   filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.06-000085          hklG4PmgQyOhE0DzNf56xg   1   1   83258752            0     80.1gb           40gb
green  open   filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.03-000084          Cplx4reTTOCcVsLg699G6g   1   1   83616802            0     80.3gb         40.1gb
green  open   filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086          iOuHk1AXQ7O9I5CV00g5PQ   1   1   71596966            0       69gb         34.4gb
green  open   filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.01-000083          3n6kWj1uSvCdFy5XFx3Ljw   1   1   84130267            0     80.2gb           40gb
```

and when I run the following search on multiple indixes, I get always the same result (hits)

```
➜ curl -s -X GET "http://172.28.162.21:9200/filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.0*/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "docker.cluster": {
              "query": "stage-cluster"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "docker-name": {
              "query": "stage-app"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2020-12-09T22:30:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2020-12-09T23:30:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    "Response"
                  ],
                  "query": "*errorCode\\\"\\:\\4\\0\\0*"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}' | grep "_index"
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
        "_index" : "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086",
```

My problem is that I cannot retrieve proper results, so I need to make sure that my search works on every index. I have confirmed via the Kibana search (GUI), that the hit results are more than 200,000 hits.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[track_total_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#track-total-hits-10000-default) defaults to 10k and if results are more than this, the response will indicate that the returned value is a lower bound.

Few questions:

1. total how many indices you are hitting?
2. Can you provide the response?

Comment: 1. From the URL that I appended, http://172.28.162.21:9200/filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.0*, I search on all indexes that are named "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12"

2. The response is only from one index, "filebeat-new-7.2.0-2020.12.09-000086"

Comment: @user515576 can you provide response and did you get a chance to look at the link I provided and verified its b/c of this limit??

Comment: again I had the same result, with no more than the expected result